# unable to install jenkins in centos 9

Tags: jenkins, centos9

I have tried to install jenkins several times by following the instruction given in the official site. But failed. Below I am giving the instructions.

```
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo \
https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo
sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key
sudo yum upgrade
# Add required dependencies for the jenkins package
sudo yum install java-11-openjdk
sudo yum install jenkins
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Though I am not using this command `sudo yum install java-11-openjdk` because I have Oracle JDK 17 and 8 Installed.

Below is the error stack starce:

```
    Total                                                                                                                                                         17 MB/s |  87 MB     00:05
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                                                                                                                                     1/1
  Running scriptlet: jenkins-2.346.2-1.1.noarch                                                                                                                                          1/1
  Installing       : jenkins-2.346.2-1.1.noarch                                                                                                                                          1/1
Error unpacking rpm package jenkins-2.346.2-1.1.noarch
  Verifying        : jenkins-2.346.2-1.1.noarch                                                                                                                                          1/1

Failed:
  jenkins-2.346.2-1.1.noarch

Error: Transaction failed
```

I have tried even by downloading the RPM directly, but it is showing key issue.

error log :

```
[root@vmi640623 tmp]# cd /home/ftp
[root@vmi640623 ftp]# rpm -ivh jenkins-2.346.2.2-1.1.noarch.rpm
warning: jenkins-2.346.2.2-1.1.noarch.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 9ff90bda: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        daemonize is needed by jenkins-2.346.2.2-1.1.noarch
[root@vmi640623 ftp]#
```

Comment: Clear `yum` cache and try again

Comment: @Romeo Ninov no change, same issue.

Comment: What happen if you install `rpm` by hand?

Comment: @Romeo Ninov please check the edit in the questin.

Comment: Try to install it on this way: `yum install daemonize jenkins`

Comment: Error: Unable to find a match: daemonize

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137809/discussion-between-romeo-ninov-and-black-swan).